# Unwanted out of memory error in ArrayList::new - Why?

Tags: java, collections, java-8

I am getting out of memory error with just **50000** objects.

I checked `computeIfAbsent` implementation but unfortunately did not find any thing peculiar.

My machine configuration is `16 GB` ram and `core I7`.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count = 50000;
        List<ListObject> list = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            int key = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(100000);
            int value = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1000000);
            list.add(new ListObject(key, value));
        }
        Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap();
        for (ListObject a : list) {
            map.computeIfAbsent(a.getKey(), ArrayList::new);
        }
        System.out.println("Done");

    }
```

and my ListObject is below:

```
class ListObject {
    public ListObject(int key, int value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(int key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    private int key;
    private int value;

}
```

Can some one please help me understand this behavior.

Comment: Any method can throw an OOM error

Comment: @Michael I reproduced this too. The curious thing is that if you replace `computeIfAbsent` with `put`, the exception goes away. Wonder whether this has to do with the implementation...

Comment: `List<ListObject> list = new ArrayList<>(count);` You forgot the diamond operator `<>`. For better speed and memory usage already reserve space for `count` items too. The same with: `new HashMap<>(count)`

Comment: @ernest_k - I checked the implementation , to be frank did not get much out of that.

Comment: Wow... Thanks @Holger. Interesting how hard it is to see the obvious :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The erroneous part is this:

```
ArrayList::new
```

What you don't realise is that this is not inferred to

```
() -> new ArrayList<>()
```

but to

```
key -> new ArrayList<>(key)
```

i.e. every list is created with a random size from 0 to 100000. Worst case that's 5 billion.